# Generating a radio button list in MVC5

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the necessary view models in place to generate the list of available addresses for a given user.
I am able to display the addresses in the structure as I intend too.

```
@if (Model.Addresses.Any())
{
    <ul class="ol">
        @foreach (var address in Model.Addresses)
        {
            <li>
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Address", address); }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

I plan to have each of these addresses prefixed with a radio button.

The model I am rendering gives me an `id`. (*say* 123456)

So the radio button for each item should have these attributes as in this example below -

```
<input type="radio" id="addressId_123456" name="addressId" value="123456"/>
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason your using a partial here? Why not just use `RadioButtonFor()` in your loop?

Comment: This same address view...will be repeated in different sections of the same page with different models. Like Billing Address and Shipping Address etc.

Comment: Then you should be using an `EditorTemplate`, not a partial (so that you get the correct name attributes for binding). And does the model in the view have a property `addressId` for binding to the selected value? And what are the other properties of the Address model that you want to display in the view

Comment: Couldn't you simply put the RadioButtonFor inside the partial? Do you need help making the RadioButtonFor?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes the model does have the property `addressId` and the other properties I need are Name, Address1 , Address2, State, PostalCode .... which I am able to indeed display in the view. The issue is just how to prefix these addresses with a radio button each with id and value as asked in the question.

Comment: `@foreach (var address in Model.Addresses) { @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAddress, item.addressId, new { id = "" }) @Html.DisplayFor(m => address.State) ..... }` where `SelectedAddress` is a property in your model that you want to bind the ID of the selected address to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a RadioButtonFor here is the code of an HTML helper with bootstrap. Thanks to @PaulDSheriff

```
#region Bootstrap/HTML 5 Radio Button
    /// <summary>
    /// Bootstrap and HTML 5 Radio Button.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper">The HTML helper instance that this method extends.</param>
    /// <param name="expression">An expression that identifies the object that contains the properties to render.</param>
    /// <param name="id">The 'id' attribute name to set.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The 'name' attribute to set.</param>
    /// <param name="text">The text to display next to this radio button.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The 'value' attribute to set.</param>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes">An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element.</param>
    /// <returns>An HTML radio button with the appropriate type set.</returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonBootstrapFor<TModel, TValue>(
          this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
          Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
          string id,
          string name,
          string text,
          string value,
          object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
      return RadioButtonBootstrapFor(htmlHelper, expression, id, name, text, value, false, false, false, htmlAttributes);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bootstrap and HTML 5 Radio Button in a Button Helper.
    /// This helper assumes you have added the appropriate CSS to style this radio button.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper">The HTML helper instance that this method extends.</param>
    /// <param name="expression">An expression that identifies the object that contains the properties to render.</param>
    /// <param name="id">The 'id' attribute name to set.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The 'name' attribute to set.</param>
    /// <param name="text">The text to display next to this radio button.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The 'value' attribute to set.</param>
    /// <param name="isChecked">Whether or not to set the 'checked' attribute on this radio button.</param>
    /// <param name="isAutoFocus">Whether or not to set the 'autofocus' attribute on this radio button.</param>
    /// <param name="useInline">Whether or not to use 'radio-inline' for the Bootstrap class.</param>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes">An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element.</param>
    /// <returns>An HTML radio button with the appropriate type set.</returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonBootstrapFor<TModel, TValue>(
      this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
      Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
      string id,
      string name,
      string text,
      string value,
      bool isChecked,
      bool isAutoFocus,
      bool useInline = false,
      object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(512);
      string htmlChecked = string.Empty;
      string htmlAutoFocus = string.Empty;
      string rdoClass = "radio";

      if (isChecked)
      {
        htmlChecked = "checked='checked'";
      }
      if (isAutoFocus)
      {
        htmlAutoFocus = "autofocus='autofocus'";
      }
      if (useInline)
      {
        rdoClass = "radio-inline";
      }

      // Build the Radio Button
      sb.AppendFormat("<div class='{0}'>", rdoClass);
      sb.Append("  <label>");
      sb.AppendFormat("    <input id='{0}' name='{1}' type='radio' value='{2}' {3} {4} {5} />", 
                      id, name, value, htmlChecked, htmlAutoFocus, 
                      GetHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
      sb.AppendFormat("    {0}", text);
      sb.Append("  </label>");
      sb.Append("</div>");

      // Return an MVC HTML String
      return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
    #endregion
```

Now as you see id, name and value are parameters. Pass them directly, in case you need another html attributes, pass them as the final parameter.
Hope this help

Comment: A terrible solution that does not even use correct 2-way model binding and has no client side validation - this shows no understanding of how `HtmlHelper` methods work (and it does not address the question)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, once you have the the id you can send the values and it will generate the input type="radio", correctly, please can you explain first why this extension method doesn't work correctly? HtmlHelpers generates a predefined code, for example Html.Raw makes returns a new HtmlString(value). Second example Html.LabelFor in conjunction with the metadata creates a TagBuilder that at the end calls tagBuilder.ToMvcHtmlString. Which is your point here? Is not generating the correct html with the Helper method?

Comment: There are far 2 many reasons to explain in a comment. Nowhere does this use the values from `ModelState`(if they exist) for correct 2-way model binding. Now where does this generate the `data-val-*` attributes necessary for client side validation.

Comment: I disagree in the second point, the data-val- attributes can be part of the last parameter, but it is something that can be handle internally as part of the helper, and you are right with the first point. But with those methods you can still generate the above html <input type="radio" id="addressId_123456" name="addressId" value="123456"/>

Comment: Then you also do not understand how to create an extension method. And I suggest you start studying the source code if you ever want to write your own. And everything in that code can be simply done correctly using one line of code - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.someProperty, someValue, new { ... })`

Comment: with that in mind, I suggest you to improve the answer, the goal here is to resolve the problem, be clever!!!

Comment: I can't until OP provides the necessary info as I have requested in the comments to the question :)